# Error on CP homepage from core/EE_Exceptions.php

Tags: control-panel, php, error

I'm trying to secure my install of EE by following the [instructions here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/best_practices.html), which involve moving my system directory above my web root, and renaming it.

My site loads fine, and I can even navigate to parts of the control panel by deep-linking into CP sections. However, when visiting the CP home, I get the following PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function send_ajax_response() on a non-object in
/Users/charlesgallant/ ... path ... /stem/expressionengine/core/EE_Exceptions.php
on line 62
```

--
EE 2.6.1, running on 
Apache 2.2.3, with php 5.3.2 (and have tested 5.4.10)

I've checked:

- File Permissions
- Disabling plugins
- Others who have found this error have mis-named some folders or failed an upgrade, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.
- Making sure the paths in all my config files are correct (which they MUST be, if I can access my site AND sections of my control panel).

I've tried commenting out some offending blocks of code around line 62, and I was able to raise this error:

```
Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller 
specified in your Routes.php file is valid.
```

...and yes, this file appears valid to the best of my knowledge.

Any thoughts are appreciated - thanks in advance =)

**==UPDATE==**

I can subvert this error and at least render the login page by adding blank query parameters to the url:

Visiting `myDomain.com/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=login` works,

Visiting `myDomain.com/admin.php?` throws the above fatal PHP error. How is this possible!?!? Either way, I still can't see the actual homepage for my control panel, so I can't accept this workaround.

Comment: Same issue here http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/gmaps-fieldtype/viewthread/10312#35599

Just added a bug report on https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19630

Comment: A known solution has been added to the bug report:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19630

Answer (score 1):

Per lealea's comment above, a solution is here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19630

There's a zip to download, so if you need this fix, visit that link.